# How should I perform this binning and averaging in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, mean, binning

I am trying to perform a binning average. I am using the code:

```
Avg = mean(reshape(a,300,144,27));
AvgF = squeeze(Avg);
```

The last line gets rid of singleton dimensions.

So as can be seen I am averaging over 300 points. It works fine except for times when I have a total number of points not equal to a multiple of 144*300.

Is there any way to make this binning average work even when the total number of points is not a multiple of 144*300?

**EDIT:** Sorry if my question sounded confusing. To clarify...

I have a file with 43200 rows and 27 columns. I am averaging by binning 300 rows at a time, which means in the end I am left with a matrix of size **144-by-27**.

My code as I wrote it above works only when I have exactly 43200 rows. In some cases I have 43199, 43194, etc.. The reshape function works when I have a total number of rows that is a multiple of 300 (the bin size). Is there a way to make this binning average work when my total number of rows is not a multiple of 300?

Comment: Without knowing what the data looks like, one idea is to pad your array with `NaN`'s to reach the desired size and use `nanmean` which the same as `mean` only ignoring NaN values.

Comment: How many total points will you be short by? One or two? Hundreds? Thousands?

Comment: in some files i have  86399, others  86395 and so  on , compared to 86400 which is what i need for the whole day. like i wrote it works if i erase more points to make it equal  to  143*300 , but i  have to manually check and erase pts .
so i was wondering if there is a a way to get it done

Comment: If your total number of points is 86,400, shouldn't the "27" in your code be a "2"?

Comment: no it should be 27 as i have 27 columns in the file

Comment: 600( not 300 as i wrote above) is the number of pts in my bin. and when i bin by 300 pts i am left with 144 total pts 43200 pts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand the problem better now...

If `a` is the data read from your file (of size **N-by-27**, where N is ideally 43,200), then I think you would want to do the following:

```
nRemove = rem(size(a,1),300);  %# Find the number of points to remove
a = a(1:end-nRemove,:);        %# Trim points to make an even multiple of 300
Avg = mean(reshape(a,300,[],27));
AvgF = squeeze(Avg);
```

This will remove points such that the number of rows in `a` will be a multiple of 300. Then your reshape and average should work. Note that I use `[]` in the call to [RESHAPE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html), which lets it figure out what the number of column should be.

Comment: @AP: I guess someone must have downvoted you since the first version was a little unclear. The newest version makes more sense, so maybe they will come remove their downvote.